# Why is R telling me that Rtools 4.0 is an incompatible version?

Tags: r, rstudio

I want to code in R language using RStudio. I'm using RStudio latest version:1.4.1106 and Rtools version: 4.0. But I have an error

"WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but no version of Rtools compatible with the currently running version of R was found. Note that the following incompatible version(s) of Rtools were found:

- Rtools 4.0 (installed at C:\rtools40)

Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

[https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/"](https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/%22)

But now I'm using RStudio latest version is 1.4.1106. What should I do to fix that error

Comment: I don't think you have anything to worry about, devtools just hasn't been updated yet to take into account R 4.1

Comment: @HongOoi Rtools ≠ devtools.

Answer (score 8):

R ≠ RStudio ≠ Rtools. These are three different pieces of software.

You need to have a version of Rtools matching your version of R installed. You can find older versions of Rtools in the [Rtools history](https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/history.html).

But it would be better to instead *update your version of R*, which seems to be well outdated (the current version of R is 4.1.0, but the error message suggests that you are running version 3.6 or earlier). To do this, download and install R from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/. (To find out which version of R you’re running, type `R.version` in the R command prompt.)

Note that the current release of RStudio does not yet support R 4.1.0 (which was just released). To make RStudio work with that version of R, you’ll then also need install the [preview version of RStudio](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/).

Alternatively, you could elect to install the previous stable version, [R 4.0.5](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/4.0.5/). This version of R will work with your version of RStudio.

Comment: What do you mean by "the current release of RStudio also does not yet support R 4.1.0"? I am using the latest version of `R` and `Rstudio` and everything seems fine. I have been hearing people talk about some issues related to that but not sure why I have not yet experienced any of them (e.g. `ggplot2` issues)

Comment: @bird No idea why you haven’t experienced any issues: they seem to be confirmed as widespread, and the official stance is that the stable release of RStudio does *not* support R 4.1.0.

Comment: Is "stable release of RStudio" the newest version of `Rstudio`? If so, I would really like to know why everything works perfectly for me while everyone else seems to have problems.

Comment: @bird “Stable release” is the newest version of RStudio that’s not the preview. I.e. 1.4.1106. I can’t tell you why you’re not having issues since I’m not using RStudio.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are attempting to install and/or use `RTools` but the version of R that you are running is incompatible with version 4.0 of `RTools`.

You need to check which version of R you are running (`R --version`) and then check to see if it is compatible with `RTools 4.0`.

If not, then I imagine you would need to upgrade your version of R in order to be able to use it.

Comment: But Rstudio latest version is 1.4 and I'm using 1.4 version. how can I upgrade ?

Comment: You use RStudio (which is an IDE) in order to code with the R language.  `R --version` checks which version of the R language you are using; `RTools` will be compatible with the version of the language you are using - not RStudio. Run `R --version` to see which version of R you are using.